# How to restrict the search of a place by the code of the country using GeoSearchControl, vuejs?

Tags: vuejs2, geolocation

Good morning, I am currently working with this bookstore
https://github.com/fega/vue2-leaflet-geosearch
I have applied the rules for the places finder in the following way:

```
geosearchOptions: {
              provider: new OpenStreetMapProvider(),
              searchLabel: '¿Que direccion buscas?',
              showMarker: true,
              showPopup: false,
              maxMarkers: 1,
              style: 'bar',
              retainZoomLevel : true
            }
```

But I want you to only show me the results of certain countries with your Country Code, since at the moment I am searching for all the places, for example:
[image]

I want to restrict only one country.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To restrict search by country for `OpenStreetMapProvider` specify `countrycodes` parameter.

[Per documentation](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim):

> `countrycodes=<countrycode>[,<countrycode>][,<countrycode>]...`
>
> Limit search results to a specific country (or a list of countries).
>   `<countrycode>` should be the ISO 3166-1alpha2 code, e.g. `gb` for the
>   United Kingdom, `de` for Germany, etc.

**Example**

```
geosearchOptions: {
    provider: new OpenStreetMapProvider({
      params: {
        countrycodes: "gb"
      }
    })
}
```